# SQL Server Exception handling in a cursor defined query

Tags: t-sql, exception, sql-server-2008-r2

Here is the script I am using to run against all the databases on sql server but somehow the script stops when the database is in transition so all I want to do is the script needs to skip the database that is in transition and proceed with rest of the databases. Any help would be appreciated.

```
declare @name varchar(max) 

SET @starttime = GETDATE() 

Declare DB_cursor cursor for
    SELECT Name 
    FROM sys.databases 
    WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb') 
      AND is_read_only = 0 
      AND is_in_standby = 0 
      AND state = 0 

OPEN DB_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM DB_cursor INTO @name 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    EXEC(' use [' + @name + '] IF EXISTS (select name from sys.objects where name=''@Tablename'') UPDATE STATISTICS [' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @TableName +'](['+@StatsName+']) WITH FULLSCAN ') 

    FETCH NEXT FROM DB_cursor INTO @name 
END

CLOSE DB_cursor
DEALLOCATE DB_cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @sql = ' use [' + @name + '] IF EXISTS (select name from sys.objects where name=''@Tablename'') UPDATE STATISTICS [' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @TableName +'](['+@StatsName+']) WITH FULLSCAN ' )

EXEC sp_executesql @sql = @sql
```